# comtypes in Python GetModule Error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 621: invalid start byte

Tags: python, encoding, comtypes

I'm using the GetModule of comtypes package in Python.
and I get the error: **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 621: invalid start byte**

```
Below the details: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

<ipython-input-5-3a53f2c64cb1> in <module>
----> 1 GetModule("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\xxxxxxxxxxxx.exe")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py in GetModule(tlib)
    109     # create and import the module
--> 110     mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
    111     try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py in _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
    171     logger.info("# Generating comtypes.gen.%s", modname)
--> 172     generate_module(tlib, ofi, pathname)
    173 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\tools\tlbparser.py in generate_module(tlib, ofi, pathname)
    749 
--> 750     gen.generate_code(list(items.values()), filename=pathname)
    751 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\tools\codegenerator.py in generate_code(self, items, filename)
    240             self.more = set()
--> 241             self.generate_all(items)
    242 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\tools\codegenerator.py in generate_all(self, items)
    188         for item in items:
--> 189             self.generate(item)
    190 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\tools\codegenerator.py in generate(self, item)
    184         self.done.add(item)
--> 185         mth(item)
    186 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\tools\codegenerator.py in External(self, ext)
    628         print("import", modname, file=self.imports)
--> 629         comtypes.client.GetModule(ext.tlib)
    630 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py in GetModule(tlib)
    109     # create and import the module
--> 110     mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
    111     try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py in _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
    183         ofi.close()
--> 184         mod = _my_import(fullname)
    185     return mod

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py in _my_import(fullname)
     23         comtypes.gen.__path__.append(comtypes.client.gen_dir)
---> 24     return __import__(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])
     25 

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 51: invalid start byte (_EA544A21_C82D_11D1_A3E4_00A0C90AEA82_9_6_0.py, line 1414)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only, running_compiled_code)
   2028                 # Though this won't be called by syntax errors in the input
   2029                 # line, there may be SyntaxError cases with imported code.
-> 2030                 self.showsyntaxerror(filename, running_compiled_code)
   2031             elif etype is UsageError:
   2032                 self.show_usage_error(value)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in showsyntaxerror(self, filename, running_compiled_code)
   2090         # If the error occurred when executing compiled code, we should provide full stacktrace.
   2091         elist = traceback.extract_tb(last_traceback) if running_compiled_code else []
-> 2092         stb = self.SyntaxTB.structured_traceback(etype, value, elist)
   2093         self._showtraceback(etype, value, stb)
   2094 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, value, elist, tb_offset, context)
   1469                 and isinstance(value.lineno, int):
   1470             linecache.checkcache(value.filename)
-> 1471             newtext = linecache.getline(value.filename, value.lineno)
   1472             if newtext:
   1473                 value.text = newtext

~\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py in getline(filename, lineno, module_globals)
     14 
     15 def getline(filename, lineno, module_globals=None):
---> 16     lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
     17     if 1 <= lineno <= len(lines):
     18         return lines[lineno-1]

~\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py in getlines(filename, module_globals)
     45 
     46     try:
---> 47         return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
     48     except MemoryError:
     49         clearcache()

~\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py in updatecache(filename, module_globals)
    135     try:
    136         with tokenize.open(fullname) as fp:
--> 137             lines = fp.readlines()
    138     except OSError:
    139         return []

~\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 621: invalid start byte
```

I'm very new on Python. I've searched some other solutions about encoding who suggests adding "encoding = xxx in the read function", but I don't konw how to find the "read" function in the comtypes package.
Anyone has any suggestions ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Doesn't look like there is an easy/quick fix. You could hack the library to turn off code caching by setting `comtypes.client.gen_dir = None`. That way the filesystem is not accessed (for code caching), and so the encoding/decoding process is bypassed.

Comment: For a better solution, what does `open('somefile.py').encoding` produce versus a python file `encoded.py` (ie. `open('encoded.py').encoding`) that explicitly starts with the characters `# -*- encoding: mbcs -*-` (this must be the very first line of the file, it cannot appear anywhere else in the file).

Comment: Thanks Dunes !  But...I didn't understand the second comment.  When a library is successfully wrapped into python, indeed python creates a xxxnumberxxx.py with the first line # -*- coding: mbcs -*-

Comment: The second comment is me asking for more information. I'm trying to figure out the encoding your computer uses by default in different scenarios. I think the author of the library assumed this would probably end up as CP-1252, but that your system is using something else. MBCS isn't a technically a character encoding, more just that it is a multi-byte character set, but without saying which one.

Comment: `comtypes.client.gen_dir = None` should cause the library to load the module from a piece of memory instead creating a file cache and loading that instead. This file cache is the where the encoding problem is coming from.

Comment: wow ! works like a magic !!! Thanks Dunes !